# Filter ansible dict attribute values without 'selectattr'

Tags: python, json, filter, ansible, jinja2

I need to parse a text file for gaps in a numbered list, then select the first missing number as an Ansible variable.

For example, with a list that looks like this:

```
100
101
102
103
104
106
107
109
110
```

My requirement is to identify the first integer missing in the sequence `100..111` from this file, in this case, it would need to select `105`.

I am currently using `lineinfile` to parse the text:

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    dest: target.txt
    regexp: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  check_mode: yes
  register: search
  loop: "{{ range(100, 111) | list }}"
```

This gives me a dictionary called `search` that contains, among other things, a `found` value for each number. I'd like to filter the dictionary to select the first number occurring with value `found: '0'`, but have so far been unsuccessful.

Due to an outdated version of Ansible and Jinja2 (that can't be updated for reasons), I don't have access to the `selectattr` or `rejectattr` filters, which I know would be the preferred way of accomplishing this. I'm currently trying to develop a workaround using *json_query* but haven't had any luck yet.

I don't care how cumbersome the final code is.

Comment: 1) please define `reasons` why you can't update because not having `selectattr` means you have a version from dinosaur age. Getting an up-to-date ansible version is as simple as `pip install --upgrade ansible`. 2) Please show the workaround you have been working on using json query and the exact problem you get. 3) Unless I miss something it seems you are over complicating this: use the file lookup to get the file content in a var, split on the new line char to get a simple list and get the first element.

Comment: In a nutshell: `{{ lookup('file', 'yourfile.txt').split'\n') | first }}`. You can get use `slurp` in place of the lookup if you need to get the file from the remote target.

Comment: @Zeitounator the requirement is to find the first integer missing in the sequence `100..111` => _My script would need to identify and select "105"._

Comment: This is indeed a much clearer description that should go as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could do a simple loop, with the conditions:

- the variable is not yet defined
- `found` is zero

```yaml
- set_fact:
    first_missing: "{{ item.item }}"
  loop: "{{ search.results }}"
  when: first_missing is not defined and item.found == 0
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=100) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=101) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=102) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=103) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=104) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=105)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=106) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=107) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=108) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=109) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=110)
```

And you effectively ends with `105` inside the variable `first_missing`.

---

But your idea to have a JMESPath query is pretty clever, and can do it too, the `set_fact` becomes as simple as:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    first_missing: >-
      {{
        search.results
        | json_query('[?found == `0`].item | [0]')
      }}
```

Where

- the expression in the square brackets `` ?found == `0` `` allows you to select all the elements of the list having `found` equal to zero
- `.item` only select the `item` attribute of the dictionaries in the list
- and the last bit resets the projection to select the first item of the list `| [0]`

---

A third solution, which is faster, is to use the [`diff`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-diff-mode) mode along with the `check_mode` on a `copy` module, recreating the file without the gaps:

```yaml
- copy:
    content: >-
      {% for i in range(100, 111) -%}
        {{ i }}
      {% endfor -%}
    dest: target.txt
  diff: yes
  check_mode: yes
  register: file
```

This will yield:

```
TASK [copy] *******************************************************************
--- before: target.txt
+++ after: /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-36701z60diga/tmp2ao9r38b
@@ -3,7 +3,9 @@
 102
 103
 104
+105
 106
 107
+108
 109
 110

changed: [localhost]
```

Sadly, the registered result is not as smooth as the output and gives one big before/after state of the file, so you fall back to a solution similar to the one proposed by [@Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72482899/2123530):

```
- set_fact:
    first_missing: >-
      file.diff.0.after.split()
      | difference(file.diff.0.before.split())
      | first
```

Comment: This was immensely helpful! Thank you!

This only leaves a minor QoL issue that I may work on later, in that the actual range I'm working with has about 100 iterations. Basically, we have a range of values between 100-199 to work with, so search.results has to spend about 1-2 minutes generating every time the script is run.

When I have time, I may return to the project and try a different 'search' method that cuts the list short once a qualifying number is found.

At any rate, thanks again for the tip!

Comment: @SaintRough added another idea, though it didn't end up as nice as I expected it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a much simpler way IMO with a very simple set of filters:

1. read your entries from your file with the `file` lookup. If the file is remote, `fetch` it first from the target or `slurp` its content into a var
2. `split` the content from the file on the new line char to obtain a list
3. map the `int` function to each list element to transform the parsed strings to integers
4. apply the `difference` filter against the range of numbers you are looking for
5. keep the fist element of the result list (after sorting for security)

Simply put as code taking for granted your file is locally available in `target.txt`

```yaml
  - name: find first missing number
    debug:
      msg: "{{ range(100, 111) | list | difference(lookup('file', 'target.txt').split('\n') | map('int')) | sort | first }}"
```

If your original list can contain values outside of the given explored range, you can simply reject the values out-of-range prior to selecting the first result

```yaml
    - name: find first missing number
      vars:
        first: 100
        last: 110
        my_range: "{{ range(first, last+1) | list }}"
        my_numbers: "{{ lookup('file', 'target.txt').split('\n') | map('int') }}"
        my_diff: "{{ my_range | difference(my_numbers) }}"
        my_diff_in_range: "{{ my_diff | reject('<', first) | reject('>', last) }}"
        my_result: "{{ my_diff_in_range | sort | first }}"
      debug:
        var: my_result
```

Comment: Found back that bit of gem from Vladimir: `query('sequence', 'start=100 end=111')` can generate a sequence of strings right away.

Comment: my extended solution needs integers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter, for example

```
shell> cat filter_plugins/range_gaps.py
def range_gaps(a):
    gaps = []
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        if a[i + 1] - a[i] > 1:
            gaps.extend(range(a[i] + 1, a[i + 1]))
    return (gaps)


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'range_gaps': range_gaps,
        }
```

Test it. The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|range_gaps|to_json }}"
      loop:
        - []
        - [100]
        - [100, 101]
        - [100, 104]
        - "{{ lookup('file', 'file.txt').splitlines()|map('int')|sort }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: '[]'
  msg: '[]'
  msg: '[]'
  msg: '[101, 102, 103]'
  msg: '[105, 108]'
```